# Spring Boot urls with .html ending

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have very simple hello world created with spring boot (just starter web, no thymeleaf etc.).
I want to handle /hello url and it should produces view from /static/view.html

I have /static/view.html and simple method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello2() {
    return "hello.html";
}
```

The problem is that it causes error:

> Circular view path [hello.html]: would dispatch back to the current
>   handler URL [/hello.html] again

I figured out that it does not matter if I visit /hello or /hello.html, Spring treats them the same.

How can I return simple, static html with the same name as the url path and which object in spring mvc/boot causes mapping url like /example.html to just /example?

Comment: Your file is named view.html, but you're returning hello.html. Why? Moreover, view.html is not a view. It's a publicly available resource. You should just forward to it.

Comment: Let's say that before showing hello.html I want to do some logic in my controller (hello.html in my example can be simple confirmation page). So i want to still do this simple thing, and the question why spring boot maps *.html as just * is still valid

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multiple-representations

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform next steps:

1. Introduce MVC configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

2. Put your **hello.html** into **/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF** folder
3. Make sure you have compile dependencies like this:

   ```
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
   compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
   ```

   I posted gradle code, if you have maven use similar xml.

**NOTE** Step 3 is the most important step because if you're using spring boot it applies auto-configurations depending on what you have in classpath. For instance if you add thymeleaf dependency

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

that will most likelly break the code because thymeleaf will introduce its own auto-configured view resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the method in your controller. A `@RequestMapping` is not needed for static content.

Comment: I guess you mean *is NOT needed*.

Comment: Absolutely... I'll fix that